# How do I calculate factorial and show working?

Tags: java

Hey I am really new to java and need a little help with this please.

I have some basic code that works fine it calculates the factor of a number lets say 5 and it gives the output answer of in this case "Factorial = 120.00"

That's great but I want it to give me the output like this "5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120.00" but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks for any help

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int nos1=0;
int total=1;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

System.out.print("Please enter number to factor ");
nos1 = kboard.nextInt();

for (int x=1;x<=nos1;x++)
{
total = total *x;   
}
System.out.println("Factorial = "+df.format(total));
}
```

Comment: Try printing something (hint: x) inside the loop. You may have to change the loop order and deal with first/last elements to get the formatting you want.

Comment: Build up a string of the things you're multiplying by? Although you'll need to either a) reverse it, or b) count backwards.

Answer (score 1):

This will only get you part of the way there.

this code will print

> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * = 120

```
for (int x=1;x<=nos1;x++)
{
    System.out.print(x + " * ");
    total = total *x;   
}
System.out.println(" = " + df.format(total));
```

I'll let you figure out a way to print it in the order you want and get rid of the last * at the end.  there are a few ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "";
for (int x = nos1; x >= 1; x--) {
    total = total * x;
    // print here it will work
    if(!s.isEmpty())
        s+="*";
    s += x;
}
System.out.println(s + "=" + df.format(total));
```

Comment: While this works, it teaches a bad pattern. Don't append to strings within a loop, use `StringBuilder`. In this case, though, keeping track of the string isn't even necessary.